# Sign up using web api odoo 8

Tags: web-services, odoo, odoo-8

How can i sign up to odoo 8 from mobile? is there any web service API like login or any other solution. please help me.

```
 common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
 common.version()
 uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
```

Comment: what do you mean by signup, create a new user?

Comment: Yes. want to create a new account for a new user

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user by calling the create method on the `res.users` model/object, like this

```
import xmlrpclib

url = "http://localhost:8069"
db = "db"
username = 'admin' # assumed username
password = 'admin' # assumed password

common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {}) # this step is very important for you to be able to query models
models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url)

new_user_id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'res.users', 'create', [{'name':"newuser", 'login':'newuser@gmail.com',
```

`new_user_id` is the id of the last record that what inserted into the database

```
'new_password':'password'}])
```

The [docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html) is pretty straightforward so you can read more about the methods you can call on models and how to do it